# call a javascript function, if the redirect comes from specific url

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

so this is my question - 
I have a redirect in my .htaccess file, which works perfectly. 
But now I need to call a js-function on the index page IF the redirect comes from /video. Is this possible? I have spend quite a long time on trying to figure this out - there is no code examples yet, so right now it is theoretical.
PS - I am using wordpress, so I've just added this to the general .htaccess - 
`Redirect 301 /video /`
I would love to hear your inputs and various methods of achieving this.

EDIT 
So I will post the updated tried out methods here - so far we got this -

```
<?php $redirectedFrom = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if(isset($redirectedFrom)): ?> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    console.log("does the console work"+ "<?php echo $redirectedFrom ?>"); 
</script> <?php endif ?>
```

This would work magically, if the redirect comes from a click link to the index (ie. menues etc.) but when I just write /video in the URL, it seems like the HTTP_REFERER is not being set, and herby not accessing the IF.
So do any of you have a fix for setting the referer, or some other solution?

Comment: So as a temporary solution, I have added the video page, and am using the  home template on that. listening to the pathname and if it contains video, then call the function - It is not optimal, and if you ever think of a better solution, then I will be glad to hear it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check for the value of :

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
```

It should contain url of previous page so you can detect your page from PHP and print something into HTML and later check with JS for printed value.

Comment: Although you can never trust it to be true.

Comment: so you are thinking something along the line of 
` <?php $redirectedFrom = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
 if(isset($redirectedFrom)): ?> 
<script type="text/javascript"> console.log(<?php $redirectedFrom ?>); </script> <?php endif ?>  `

Comment: $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] should give you URL of page that was displayed before user come to current page. So you can check is that referer page your video page and depending on that if result do something.

Comment: like I updated in my question : it won't work when the redirect is just an URL, redirecting through .htaccess - the HTTP-REFERER isn't being set :-(